# How do I get SQLite to run faster with PRAGMA synchronous = OFF by default

Tags: database, sqlite

I just created a new SQLite database from the command line and I have a ODBC connection to the SQLite database.
If I issue it queries, by default, the synchronous seems to be "ON" which is really slowing down INSERT performance big-time.

How do I get a SQLite database to default to **`PRAGMA synchronous = OFF`**  without needing to send a SQL command for it to do so?  Can i create a .INI file or something to enable it?

Comment: Probably not, but maybe you would like to enclose all your `INSERT` s in a single transaction (`BEGIN; INSERT... ; INSERT...; [...]; COMMIT;`). Not doing so dramatically turns performance down. Also see SQLite FAQ where this is explained very well.

Comment: i know about the transaction thing but I have an already developed application in Java that cannot be converted to using transactions and the INSERTs are really slow, making it unusable unless i figure out how to stop SQLlite from verifying each insert and creating pauses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately for everyone, after letting this question sit for 6 days, I finally figured out the answer.   The [SQLite ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)  seems to be the answer.   If you create a DSN, it allows you to set Sync to "OFF" in the DSN settings.   Very convenient.

Comment: With full sync Im getting 96rps,  with Normal sync I get 120rps, and with Sync OFF I am getting about 260rps.   Not much of a difference but at least its something.

Comment: To compare, I get about 600rps with MS Access.

Comment: Just for comparison, we get on average 25K-50K inserts per second when inserting into non-indexed tables in Windows.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite runs on FULL synchronous by default. There is no INI, nothing to change except when connected. However, this need only be set once per session, so you could change your project's connection function to add the "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" command after the connection. That would be actually the cleanest and quickest approach.

But if you truly want SQLite to open your database with synchronization off by default, you might want to recompile SQLite with a different default.

For the current release (3.7.3), look for variable `safety_level` in sqlite.c of the [sqlite-amalgamation source](http://sqlite.org/download.html):

Change:

```
safety_level = 3;
```

To:

```
safety_level = 1;
```

(Yes, it's one off from the shell setting.) In the `openDatabase` function (and `attachFunc` if you wish).

---

If you really need this process accelerated, as stated in the comments you will have at the very least to consider transactions. Down the road, this is the preferred solution. It might not be the easiest, or the most possible (time is after all limited to all), but it's the cleanest, sanest, easiest to maintain in the long term. (I just had to get that off my chest. Done!)

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  it wasn't quite what I needed but I want to thank you.

Comment: @djangofan: You're welcome, and I'm glad you found a cleaner solution than doing a special build.

Answer (score 3):

In Java I use following snippet on getConnection method.So whenever I get new connection, synchronous will be disabled.

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:lms.db");        
    Statement st = con.createStatement();        
    String sql="PRAGMA synchronous=OFF";
    st.execute(sql);
```

Comment: Yes this is the standard approach in C# too.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since the last answer in this topic, but if someone like me was looking for a way to set 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF' but couldn't keep an SQLite connection alive (I have my reasons); what I did was setting the 'PRAGMA synchronous=OFF' at the begging of the Query and then doing the regular stuff aftewards, separating then by a semi-colon (;), just like this:

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF; INSERT INTO [...]
```

Don't know if this is a best practice, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, in Windows the PRAGMA statements must be executed *after* the database has been opened, not before.